# Error with rails s

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, sqlite, rubygems

So when I try to fire up my server using `rails s` I get

```
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481@railstutorial_rails_4_0/gems/sqlite3-1.3.8/lib/sqlite3.rb:6:in `require': cannot load such file -- sqlite3/sqlite3_native (LoadError)
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481@railstutorial_rails_4_0/gems/sqlite3-1.3.8/lib/sqlite3.rb:6:in `rescue in <top (required)>'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481@railstutorial_rails_4_0/gems/sqlite3-1.3.8/lib/sqlite3.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481@global/gems/bundler-1.6.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in `require'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481@global/gems/bundler-1.6.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in `block (2 levels) in require'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481@global/gems/bundler-1.6.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `each'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481@global/gems/bundler-1.6.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `block in require'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481@global/gems/bundler-1.6.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:61:in `each'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481@global/gems/bundler-1.6.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:61:in `require'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481@global/gems/bundler-1.6.2/lib/bundler.rb:132:in `require'
    from /Users/idrisk/rails_projects/first_app/config/application.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481@railstutorial_rails_4_0/gems/railties-4.0.5/lib/rails/commands.rb:74:in `require'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481@railstutorial_rails_4_0/gems/railties-4.0.5/lib/rails/commands.rb:74:in `block in <top (required)>'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481@railstutorial_rails_4_0/gems/railties-4.0.5/lib/rails/commands.rb:71:in `tap'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481@railstutorial_rails_4_0/gems/railties-4.0.5/lib/rails/commands.rb:71:in `<top (required)>'
    from bin/rails:4:in `require'
    from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
```

I've tried using `sudo` also, but then I get

```
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p481/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/dependency.rb:247:in `to_specs': Could not find railties (>= 0) amongst [bundler-1.6.2, bundler-unload-1.0.2, executable-hooks-1.3.1, gem-wrappers-1.2.4, rubygems-bundler-1.4.3, rvm-1.11.3.9] (Gem::LoadError)
    from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p481/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/dependency.rb:256:in `to_spec'
    from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p481/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems.rb:1231:in `gem'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481@railstutorial_rails_4_0/bin/rails:18:in `<main>'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481@railstutorial_rails_4_0/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481@railstutorial_rails_4_0/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `<main>'
```

I'm not really sure what this means. I've tried restarting and things in that sort of nature. But nothing seemed to work. Ideas?

Comment: OSX Mavericks @72DFBF5BA0DF5BE9

Comment: "gem update" then "gem install rails"

Comment: Same errors still @72DFBF5BA0DF5BE9

Comment: "gem install sqlite3"

Comment: Installing..... @72DFBF5BA0DF5BE9

Comment: Still not working @72DFBF5BA0DF5BE9

Comment: Still getting the same error @SSR

Comment: Then get rvm stable and set it to default. like rvm use <your ruby 2.0.0-p485> => or take a look here http://rvm.io/gemsets/using

Answer (score 0):

Try updating Ruby and Rails with RVM - RVM is a command-line tool which allows you to easily install, manage, and work with multiple ruby environments from interpreters to sets of gems.

Here is the website: https://rvm.io/

Comment: Maybe try creating a new Rails application to see if it is problem with your rails installation or problem with the application. Rails new Example

Comment: Create a gemset and assign a value to .rvmrc file. then just run bundle command.

Comment: If you created a new rails application and then directly pressed rails s and receive the rails options, you most likely didn't go into the directory of the new application. Try it again going into the directory Cd example. Then rails s